# better efficiency when select the largest number in a column from mysql table

Tags: mysql

In the following table, I need to select the highest score for a student regardless of course. The possible score are 5, 4, to 0. I could use basic `select distinct score order by` to get the result. But the statement scans the whole table and do sorting, which is quit time-consuming. Since there are only 5 possible values for the target, I believe a better efficiency solution exists.

```
CREATE TABLE `course_score` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100048 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Why not index scores?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use max() aggregate function

```
select max(score) 
from course_score
```

OR if you need student wise max score you can do following -

```
 select student_id,max(score) 
    from course_score group by student_id
```

Comment: I was thinking more like if it has a 5 then quit; if it does not have 5 but has a 4 then quit. Bad idea for mysql statement?

Comment: I don't see what advantage this 'solution' confers.